# How to: "Get user numbers for users who played the same game on all consoles."

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been attempting this query for hours. My current query just gives every user number and ignores almost all of the nested queries. For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.UNum
FROM Plays AS p
WHERE p.CNum IN
     (SELECT p.CNum
     FROM Plays AS p
     WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT COUNT(p.GNum) AS GNumCount, COUNT(p.UNum) AS UNumCount
          FROM Plays AS p
          GROUP BY p.CNum
          HAVING COUNT(p.GNum) = COUNT(p.UNum)));
```

This just gives U10-U50. THE ANSWER I WANT TO RETURN IS U20 USING A NESTED QUERY. Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong and how to fix it. Thanks.

|Users|

```
---------------------------------------
| UNum | UserName | Mastery | Hometown|
---------------------------------------
| U10  | Sheldon   | 20  | Tokyo |
| U20  | Missy   | 10  | NewYork |
| U30  | Meemaw   | 30  | NewYork |
| U40  | George   | 20  | Tokyo |
| U50  | Mary | 30  | Seattle |
```

|Games|

```
---------------------------------------
| GNum | GameName | ListPrice | Version | CityCreated |
---------------------------------------
| G100  | Pong   | 9.99  | 12 | Tokyo |
| G200  | PacMan   | 24.99  | 6 | NewYork |
| G300  | Zelda   | 19.99  | 8 | Peking |
| G400  | Doom   | 9.99  | 15 | Tokyo |
| G500  | MarioBros | 19.99  | 10 | NewYork |
| G600  | Pitfall | 9.99  | 4 | Tokyo |
```

|Consoles|

```
---------------------------------------
| CNum | ConsoleName | Price | ManuLoc |
---------------------------------------
| C1  | Atari   | 99.99  | NewYork |
| C2  | Intellivision   | 129.99  | Peking |
| C3  | Nintendo   | 119.99  | Seattle |
| C4  | PlayStation   | 89.99  | Seattle |
| C5  | Coleco | 189.99  | Tokyo |
| C6  | GameBoy | 129.99  | Poughkeepsie |
| C7  | SegaGenesis | 129.99  | Tokyo |
```

|Plays|

```
---------------------------------------
| UNum | GNum | CNum | TimesPlayed |
---------------------------------------
| U10  | G100 | C1  | 22 |
| U10  | G100 | C4  | 72 |
| U20  | G300 | C1  | 44 |
| U20  | G300 | C2  | 25 |
| U20  | G300 | C3  | 27 |
| U20  | G300 | C4  | 55 |
| U20  | G300 | C5  | 69 |
| U20  | G300 | C6  | 44 |
| U20  | G300 | C7  | 86 |
| U20  | G500 | C2  | 14 |
| U30  | G300 | C1  | 21 |
| U30  | G400 | C2  | 52 |
| U40  | G600 | C3  | 33 |
| U40  | G600 | C7  | 38 |
| U50  | G100 | C4  | 15 |
| U50  | G200 | C2  | 27 |
| U50  | G200 | C4  | 14 |
| U50  | G300 | C4  | 2 |
| U50  | G400 | C4  | 8 |
| U50  | G500 | C4  | 44 |
| U50  | G500 | C5  | 56 |
| U50  | G500 | C7  | 1 |
| U50  | G600 | C2  | 24 |
| U50  | G600 | C4  | 55
```

Comment: What have you tried? We are glad to help, but you have to show the effort you have already made and what issue you are having.

Comment: yeah i realized that sorry. i just edited.

Comment: As not all games can be played on all consoles, you need a table `ConsoleGames` with PK of Games and Consoles as FK to specify the consoles a game can be played on. The table plays should contain an entry for every time a game is played with timestamp. Then you can count the times it was played. This allows you to know when a games was played and you can determe the moment the game was played on all consoles.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, first `GROUP BY` user and game. In a `HAVING` clause check, that the count of distinct consoles equal the count of all consoles. That should give you the user game pairs of the games the user has played on all consoles. USe `DISTINCT` to get every user only once.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       unum
       FROM plays
       GROUP BY unum,
                gnum
       HAVING count(DISTINCT cnum) = (SELECT count(*)
                                             FROM consoles)) x;
```

Comment: also where is the x coming from?

Comment: I changed up the code using 'SELECT DISTINCT p.UNum
FROM Plays AS p
GROUP BY p.UNum, p.GNum
HAVING COUNT(p.CNum) = 
     (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM consoles);' and that seemed to work, thanks.

Comment: @motto If this answer works for you, please mark it as accepted and upvote it to show others with a similar issue what to do (and as reward for the effort of sticky bit).